# Cannot create a content-type in Contentful

Tags: contentful, contentful-management, contentful-api

I am pretty new to Contentful and am using the company's contentful account.
This profile has administrator access and I cannot create a content-type.
The 'Add Content type' button appears disabled.
I checked if there is a limit on the number of Content Types that can be added,
On Demand Tier can have 500 content types and Committed Tier can have 1000 content types.
I have a lot of different spaces and I checked, that we have only 99 content types created combining all of the spaces in this account.

Is this somehow related to roles and permissions?

If thats the case shouldn't I have the ability to create a new content type since I have administrator privileges?

Answer (score 3):

The limits you mention are the [technical limits](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/technical-limits/) of the maximum possible for any space type. Most likely what's happening is related to the size of space you have. [Contentful's pricing model](https://www.contentful.com/pricing/?faq_category=payments-subscriptions&faq=what-type-of-spaces-can-i-have) allows you to choose the size of the space you need for your project and, for example, perhaps your space is a Small space which includes a maximum of 24 content types. You can see your space usage and limits from inside the Contentful webapp under Settings->Usage.